# sencha touch 2 history.back() does not work?

Tags: touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am working with a sencha touch 2 MVC application. In my app.js file i have no launch() method and

```
controllers: ['HomeController'],
```

and my HomeController routes

```
       routes: {
        '': 'viewHomePage',                       //1st page
        'ap': 'viewContactPage',                  //2nd page
        'ap/:id': 'viewContactPageById'           //3rd page
       //others
    }
```

in 2nd and 3rd page i have a button

```
xtype:'button',
listeners: {
                    tap: function () {
                        history.back();
                    }
                }
```

now the problem is that history.back() does not works in case of page2. but it works well incase of page3.

if this is special case then how to restart my application.

and if it does not works in case of MVC then what is the soln? 
or there is any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Chris, but history.back() can be made to work with a Sencha Touch 2 app. As long as your controller uses redirectTo(url), the standard history.back() will function as expected.

So if in a controller you redirect from the current url to another, using history.back() after the redirection will return you to the original url.

Answer (score 0):

If you have copied old buttons and their tap events than you have a naming conflict which causes this problem.

Rename all your new buttons to unique names and delete and create the tap events again

Answer (score -1):

history.back() redirects to the previous URL. A sencha touch app is contained within a single URL without any redirects. It works by having a stack of containers upon each other. However, they are all contained within the same page so history.back() won't work.

You need to change the way you think about redirections within a sencha touch app. Basically, in order to go 'back' you need to switch the view. You can do this by using the following code:

```
 Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({
      xtype: 'yourxtype'
 });
```

This code switches the view from the current one to the xtype you choose.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. You can use redirectTo('url') with routes, and then the function that handles that route should be the one doing the 'setActiveItem' call.